# How do I use colorama inside a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, colorama

I'm trying to change individual existing lines inside an existing tuple. Example:

```
for row in cursor:
     print(f'''
     
    ID: ........... {row[0]}
    Name: ......... {row[1]}
    Age: .......... {row[2]}
    Condition: .... {row[3]}
    Medicine: ..... {row[4]}
    Temperament: .. {row[5]}
    Adoptable: .... {row[6]}
    ''')
```

I want ID to be one color, Name, Age, Condition, Medicine, Temperament, and Adoptable to be a different color.

I can't figure out how to enter the escape codes for color inside the existing tuple. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend `Fore.<COLOR>` and preferably append  `Style.RESET_ALL` to every element you want to style.

```
from colorama import Fore, Style

row = ('a', 'b')
print(f'''
ID: ........... {Fore.YELLOW + row[0] + Style.RESET_ALL}
Name: ......... {Fore.BLUE + row[1] + Style.RESET_ALL}
''')
```

[image]

Comment: Doing that just produced the following error:

Error while fetching data from MySQL can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @Robert obviously if something is not a string you'll need to convert it first, ie `str(row[0])`

Comment: AHHH, that's what I'd forgotten! Thanks, @DeepSpace.  Row 0 is an int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, and I didn't think I could change that before concatenation since when I did the vscode text colors changed. Very grateful!